# Duplicating words on same line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editor, editing

I have a list of table names in Notepad++:

```
employee
manager
customer
reciepts
customer_details
employee_mapping
manager_employee_mapping
```

I want each word to be duplicated again in the same line, for example:

```
employee employee
manager manager
customer customer
```

And so on. I want to do this to make a SQL script where I have to select tablename as string and table's total count. Like:

```
select 'employee', count(1) from employee    union
select 'manager', count(1) from manager     union
```

similarly for all rows.
Now, words like `select/union/count/,/from` can easily be inserted using either ctrl+F or insertion at beginning and end. But getting the table name as a string is tricky.

Is there any way to do this in Notepad++ without doing this manually?
This list is just a sample, I have a list of more than 100 tables. Please help out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\w+$`
- Replace with: `select '$0', count\(1\) from $0    union`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
\w+         # 1 or more word character [a-zA-Z0-9_], this will be kept in group 0
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Toto. It solved my problem instantly. But I still didn't understand the use of ^\w+$. Could you please give me an article to study the use of regex in notepad++.

Comment: @SidhantGupta: `\w` matches a word character i.e. uppercase letter, lowercase letter, digit or underscore. You'll find usefull information [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)